# как выбрать один из нескольки классов

Tags: javascript, jquery

как выбрать один из нескольки классов?
кликнув например на первый спан хочу получить только класс example2, а получаю example1 example2, как поправить?

```
<span class="example1 example2">text</span>
<span class="example3 example4">text</span>
<span class="example5 example6">text</span>

<script>
    $(document).on("click","span",function(){
        var cls=$(this).attr("class")
        console.log(clr)
    })
</script>
```

Comment: вы уверены что хотите именно **получить** класс? а не проверить, что класс присутствует?

Comment: @Grundy да именно класс,я же и написал

Comment: именно строку _example2_? вы уверены что это именно то, что вам действительно нужно?

Comment: @Grund??? только класс example2

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под _классом_? просто строку???

Comment: я хочу чтобы у меня в переменной cls было значение  example2

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34072/discussion-between-grundy-and-cheburashkarf).

Comment: Человек хочет просто выбрать из атрибута class, значение example2

Comment: @ChromeChrome, а вот и нет, он хочет выбрать именно класс со второго места

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень интересный вопрос. Можно так, к примеру. А вообще, очень странно, да.

```
$(document).on("click","span",function(){
    var cls=$(this).attr("class");
    console.log(cls.split(" ")[1])
})
```

Comment: плохое решение, так как порядок классов в строке не определен и может быть любым :)

Comment: @Grundy насколько я понял из вопроса, ему нужен именно второй класс (по позиции).

Comment: я думаю это стоит уточнить, возможно, в итоге окажется, что надо было просто проверить наличие класса

Comment: я же написал выше что нет,мне не нужна проверка а нужно значение

Comment: @cheburashkarf пересмотрите свое видение кода. Как было уже отмечено, порядок классов в проектах чаще всего неопределен(или определен глубоко в бэкенде). Если вам потребовался класс в определенной позиции, вы, скорее всего, городите костыль.

Comment: @ПавелВайсберг, да, судя по всему ваш ответ подходит :)

Answer (score 0):

вынес мыслю из чата

```
if(element has class example2)
    cls = 'example2'
```

Comment: Вы бы лучше пояснили зачем это вам. Боюсь эта мысля из чата не тянет на ответ в текущей формулировке. Соседний ответ явно правильный, но меня мучает мысль: "Зачем это?" Почитайте http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709